# Play Scala : Recursive web services call without using Await.result

Tags: web-services, scala, recursion, playframework-2.2

I work with `Play! Scala 2.2` and I need to make recursive web services call (until I get all the results).
For the moment I managed to make it with `Await.result` as following :

```
def getTitleSetFromJson( jsValue: JsValue ): Set[ String ] = {
  val titleReads: Reads[Option[String]] = (__ \\ "title").readNullable[String]
  (jsValue \ "response" \ "songs")
    .asOpt[Set[Option[String]]](Reads.set(titleReads))
    .getOrElse(Set.empty)
    .flatten    
}

def findEchonestSongs(start: Long, echonestId: String): Future[Set[String]] = {
  val titleReads: Reads[Option[String]] = (__ \\ "title").readNullable[String]
  val endpoint = s"$baseUrl/artist/songs"
  val assembledUrl = s"$endpoint?api_key=$echonestApiKey&id=$artistId&format=json&start=$start&results=20"

  WS.url(assembledUrl).get().map { songs =>
    if ((songs.json \ "response" \ "total").asOpt[Int].getOrElse(0) > start + 20) {
      getTitleSetFromJson(songs.json) ++
        Await.result( findEchonestSongs(start + 20, echonestId), 3.seconds )
    } else {
      getTitleSetFromJson(songs.json) 
    }
  }
}
```

Now I would like to make the same thing but with the non blocking way i.e. without using `Await.result` but with everything I tried I got errors : types mismatch because of the nested futures.

Could you please give me the way to do this?

Comment: I already tried it but I get an error that I don't manage to resolve : 
type mismatch;
found   : scala.concurrent.Future[Set[String]]
 required: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?]
at           findEchonestSongs(start + 20, echonestId)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different ways to achieve your requirement. But maybe the simplest way is using [`flatMap`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future@flatMap[S](f:T=>scala.concurrent.Future[S])(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[S]).

Here is an improved version of your function (for making it simpler I took the liberty to make it return a `Future[Set[JsValue]])`.

```
import play.api.libs.json.JsValue
import play.api.libs.ws.WS
import scala.concurrent.Future
import play.api.Play.current
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object Test {

  val apiKey = "//YOUR_ECHONEST_API_KEY//"
  val baseUrl = "http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4"

  def findSongs(start: Long, artistId: String): Future[Set[JsValue]] = {

    def endpoint = s"$baseUrl/artist/songs"
    def assembledUrl = s"$endpoint?api_key=$apiKey&id=$artistId&format=json&start=$start&results=20"
    def response = WS.url(assembledUrl).get()
    def futureJson = response map (_.json)
    futureJson flatMap { result =>
      def total = (result \ "response" \ "total").asOpt[Int]
      def songs = (result \ "response" \ "songs").as[Set[JsValue]]
      total exists (_ > start + 20) match {
        case false => Future.successful(songs)
        case true => findSongs(start + 20, artistId) map (songs ++ _)
      }
    }

  }

}
```

### Working on the result

If you really want a `Set[String]` you can easily use `map` on the result.

```
val sample = findSongs(0, "someone")
sample.map(_.map(_ \ "title").map(_.as[String]))
```

### Improvements

There is a lot of room for improvement here. For instance there is no need to pass the `artistId` every time you cal the function recursively. So we can define an inner function which is recursive.

It is not that difficult to make it tail recursive by using an accumulator.

Finally it might make sense to use a `Seq[Future]` and use `fold` instead of recursion, which is again a common pattern in functional programming. But all these stuff are already provided nicely by `Stream` api. You can refer to the [`Stream` API](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream) for more info.

Comment: Let me know if you are interested in improvements part (using `Stream` for instance will make it a lot easier). By the way the whole thing is a bit weird. If you want to fetch all the songs why not increase the limit? Is there any limitation on their API?

Comment: Thank you very much for your perfect detailed response! For your question, yes there is a limitation on their API (100 results maximum but for my tests I changed 100 to 20). I'm also very interested and I would be very curious to see your improvements with the use of the Stream API.

Comment: No problem :) Will try to write a version with `Stream`s and update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can map the results from other ( from nested call ) future to be added to current Set.

Also... One very important thing. `Readability Counts`... Specially on StackOverFLow.

```
def findEchonestSongs(start: Long, echonestId: String): Future[Set[String]] = {

  val titleReads: Reads[Option[String]] = (__ \\ "title").readNullable[String]

  val requestUrl = "http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/artist/songs?api_key=" + echonestApiKey + "&id=" + echonestId +
  "&format=json&start=" + start + "&results=20"

  WS.url( requestUrl ).get().flatMap { songs =>

    var nTotal = (songs.json \ "response" \ "total").asOpt[Int].getOrElse(0)

    if( nTotal > start + 20 ) {

      val titleSet = getTitleSetFromJson( songs.json )

      val moreTitleSetFuture = findEchonestSongs( start + 20, echonestId )

      moreTitleSetFuture.map( moreTitleSet =>  titleSet ++ moreTitleSet )

    }  
    else {
      Future.successful( getTitleSetFromJson( songs.json ) )
    }
  }
}

def getTitleSetFromJson( jsValue: JsValue ): Set[ String ] = {
   (songs.json \ "response" \ "songs")
    .asOpt[Set[Option[String]]](Reads.set(titleReads))
    .getOrElse(Set.empty)
    .flatten
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I totally agree with your comment "Readability Counts" and I'm going to edit my answer and be more careful with this in the future. By the way, your response doesn't work, I get a compilation error :  `type mismatch;
scala.concurrent.Future[scala.collection.immutable.Set[String]], required: Set[String]`

Comment: You also have to use Future.successful as it is shown in the Nader Hadji Ghanbari' answer.

Comment: Yes... you will need  Future.successful in this case.